# Include synonyms in solr

Tags: solr, synonym

i am using solr for my searches. in this i found a synonyms.text file in which you can include synonyms manually for the words u want.

But as i suppose it would be very hard to include synonyms manually for each word as my application has large data.

I want to know is there any way that this synonym.text file generate automatically referring to all dictionary words

Answer (score 0):

Thats imho not possible. You need at least a semantic relation between two words i.e tokens. IF you have something like a database including semantic synonym relations you can of course generate this data.

One example source would be wiktonary (XML Dump: [Link](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aDownload)). But there maybe other example dictionaries available but i think you will not get such a exhaustive source as you wish. Parsing the XML Dump of Wiktonary is maybe your best choice and you can even align synonyms across different languages if you happen to have a multi language index.